# H2 Database not creating or accessing

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, h2

My H2 Database (lastest stable version) isn't loading or creating from different methods that I've tried, let me show below what I've done so far:

My domain:

```
@Entity
public class Categoria implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
private String nome;

public Categoria() {

}
```

My resources:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping(value="/categorias")
public class CategoriaResource {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Categoria> listar() {

    Categoria cat1 = new Categoria(1, "Informática");
    Categoria cat2 = new Categoria(2, "Escritório");

    List<Categoria> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(cat1);
    lista.add(cat2);


    return lista;
}
```

Then comes my application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/h2/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

When I try to open the localhost:8080 and input JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:file:~/h2/test it pop's the error:

> Database "C:/Users/XXX/h2/test" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we
>   cant auto-create it [90146-199] 90146/90146 (Help)

The URL: jdbc:h2:file:~/test is not showing any Databases inside of it, it's empity.

The URL:jdbc:h2:test

A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:test;IFEXISTS=TRUE". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-199] 90011/90011 (Help)

And finally the URL: jdbc:h2:mem:test

> Database "mem:test" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant
>   auto-create it [90146-199] 90146/90146 (Help)

I really don't know what to do anymore, tried everything so far.
What can I do to access even from memory or local?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: If using hibernate try adding this - spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect AND spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop AND try memory instead of file like this - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test. Try these and share the results. If it works it has to do with your filepath etc or the permissions.

Comment: Hi @AjayKumar  I managed to connect using your advices, so what can I do to ajust this filepath or even my permissions, I'm already in the administrator user.

Comment: To give you an hint - If using Eclipse etc, Try running eclipse as Administrator (it looks like you are using Windows). Or try giving the path to your user's desktop path. The whole idea is the user in this picture should have full access to the directory. Hope you got the idea now.

Comment: Well, can I input a fixed path for my URL? Like jdbc:h2:file:/C:/Users/XXX/test ? Because I managed to get the Users folder permission for full control, so now I can access the URL jdbc:h2:file:~/h2/test, this one don't gives any error from now, but still no sheets inside of it, it's just empty.

Comment: And it's so weird why I'm getting error in this:  jdbc:h2:mem:test before giving the every permission it needs, well, if I manage to access the database content from a fixed path it will be enough for me.